# Update heavly customized but stock rom Nexus 5 keeping data?

Tags: updates, root-access, bootloader, ota-update, stock-android

I have a **Google Nexus 5** with **Stock** Rom **4.4.2** and:

1. Unlocked boot-loader
2. Custom recovery (TWRP)
3. Custom kernel (franco)
4. Root
5. X-posed framework

What is the **best** method to upgrade to the upcoming version 4.4.3*, **keeping data**?

Please answer with a step-by-step guide, possibly referring to this configuration (like: *disable #5, revert #3 and #2 to stock, don't use OTA but this package from here, etc...*)

Would be great to have technical explanation for each step, to make this Q&A useful for any 4.4.x-to-4.4.y Android upgrade.

Thank you.

*look at first comment

Comment: I know 4.4.3 is not yet released, but I want to be prepared :-) the link to the package can be added later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't need to disable anything :-)**

Step-by-step guide:

1. Update your *recovery* to the latest version
2. Download this [*4.4.3 update*](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23501681358541440) and [*SuperSu*](http://download.chainfire.eu/446/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.99r3.zip?retrieve_file=1)
3. Place these files in *sdcard*
4. Boot in *recovery*
5. Wipe *Cache* and *Dalvik Cache*
6. Flash *4.4.3 update* and *SuperSu* (~15/25 mins)
7. Reboot
8. Re-install X-posed framework from its installer
9. Re-install custom kernel

Now you have 4.4.3 and all of your customization without losing data ;-)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>According to [Tested.com](http://www.tested.com/tech/android/460074-how-use-xposed-framework-android-extreme-customization/), reverting changes made by Xposed, making the OTA update and enabling Xposed tweaks again should be enough.</strike>

EDIT: Sorry, you need to go back to full Stock. Here's step by step guide: [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/general/tutorial-how-to-flash-factory-image-t2513701).

Comment: The presence of **custom recovery** and **custom kernel** doesn't matter?

Comment: See the edit above. Sorry it took so long.

Comment: I found the right way - no need to go back to full stock. Check the current accepted answer.